# how to prevent later code getting executed first in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

i am working in `shouldPrepareForSegue` method but i am stuck in a problem

```
__block BOOL Stat;

if([identifier isEqualToString:@"SignOut"]){
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Are You Sure?" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *can = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            Stat = NO;
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
        }];
        UIAlertAction *sign = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"SIGN OUT" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            Stat = YES;
            NSLog(@"%d",Stat);
        }];

        [alert addAction:can];
        [alert addAction:sign];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{}];

    NSLog(@"%d",Stat);
    return Stat;

}else{
    return YES;
}
```

value of Stat always returns 0 as it is getting executed before i respond to `UIAlertController` as the later code are getting executed first how to prevent it.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `shouldPrepareForSegue`, but rather in call the UIAlertController show and in  `can` `UIAlertAction` [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignOut" sender:nil]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function with completion block like below and call this where you need and just check flag

```
- (void)signOutWithcompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL flag))completionHandler

if([identifier isEqualToString:@"SignOut"]){
  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Are You Sure?" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  UIAlertAction *can = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    completionHandler(NO);
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
  }];
  UIAlertAction *sign = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"SIGN OUT" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    completionHandler(YES);
    NSLog(@"%d",Stat);
  }];

  [alert addAction:can];
  [alert addAction:sign];
  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{}];
}else{
  completionHandler(YES);
}
```

Comment: i have already done the same but was thinking if we can handle segue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running code that is essentially asynchronous, returning a value from the calling method is not going to work well (unless you set up some fairly complicated blocking).

Your best bet is to have the caller provide a delegate or listen for a notification instead of depending on the returned value.  That way, you can trigger whatever you need to have happen in your completion handlers.